# How to detect if bash shell command is followed by a logical && AND or || OR?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I like to have short names for common build commands I use. I also like them to `notify-send` me when they're done so that I can multi-task while I wait and not watch the terminal.

Now, I'd like the commands to not notify if I chain them. e.g.

```
  alias b='command and parameters for my build; notify-send'
  alias b2='command and parameters for a second type of build; notify send'

  $ b
  // I am notified when it completes, just once.

  $ b && b2
  // Today, I am notified twice, when b completes and when b2 does.
  // I would like to only be notified when they all complete.
  // (and I would rather not type b && b2 && notify-send)
```

So, can commands detect that they are followed by an `&&` or `||` in bash?

Comment: In theory, one _could_ implement this in bash -- it tracks a distinction between checked and unchecked commands for purposes of `set -e`; one could send a patch upstream that exposed the status of this flag; however, it's not currently accessible.

Comment: That said, `if foo` also sets the `checked` flag, so that may or may not be exactly what you want anyhow (if you quite literally _only_ want to trigger on `&&` or `||`).

Answer (score 4):

No. The general answer is to move notification outside of your commands:

```
b && b2; notify-result $?
```

---

Now, if you're implementing `b` and `b2` as shell functions rather than external commands, you *can* do some introspection -- looking at the `BASH_SOURCE` array to inspect the stack frames involved in code's invocation -- but that's extremely fragile, and by no means a good practice.